Modern LaTeX practices/characters/Unicode
I'm working on generating a family genealogy using LaTeX, and would like to know the current recommended approach for diacritical marks.
Background: The .tex file is produced by Visual Basic code running behind a Microsoft Access database (ugh). Diacritical marks have been a pain for multiple versions (I've been doing this every 5 years since about 1985!). Right now, the data has LaTeX symbols in it (e.g. Ch\'{e}rau to produce an accent-acute). The person doing the data-entry does not know LaTeX, so getting the non-ascii characters right has been a persistent pain point.
Current status: I find that I can also just put Chérau in my document (which I guess means that LaTeX now likes UTF-8).  But with someone in the family now married to someone from Turkiye, things are getting more complicated. From a bit of searching, it seemed that \usepackage[turkish]{babel} was the way to go. But then the answer provided here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401659/errors-in-using-turkish-characters-despite-using-relevant-codes-and-packages -- shows that it's not necessary. But that solution still uses diacritical markup like \u{g}, \c{c}, \"{o}, and even {\i}. To be honest, it feels as if it might be a bit of a hack compared to using a package specifically designed to handle Turkish markup.
And then there's this answer from egreg that goes into details that are far beyond my understanding as a user of LaTeX, but which suggest that UTF-8 might suffice for all this. And I'm slightly hopeful that whatever committee helps standardize Unicode will get the Turkish characters "right" rather than creating them from what might be "a bunch of similar but not identical marks used in other languages" --- TBH, I'm not sure where Turkish character sets originated or anything about their history, but I'd like to get it right.
The question: Can someone recommend a good and well-accepted way (as of 2024!) to get diacritical and other-language symbols into my LaTeX document?
The stylistic guide rules have obviously changed since 1985 when I started this project.

note that if the foreign characters are just in names you probably don't need to specify the language with babel which sets up hyphenation and fixed texts such as "Table of Contents".  Turkish for example doesn't need any different fonts.  Of course it is different if you need Arabic (or even Greek) which does require more setup. If you are expecting a lot of different scripts I would use OpenType fonts and lualatex not pdflatex and classic 8-bit tex fonts.

Do \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and use UTF-8 input. T1-encoded fonts support the whole Turkish alphabet.

David -- I'm having trouble confidently parsing your last sentence. Does it mean "Instead of pdflatex and classic 8-bit fonts, I would use OpenType fonts and lualatex"? I think that so far most cousins/in-laws are happy with anglicizations of their names (e.g. Al-Khwarizmi rather than something in an Arabic script, and similarly for, say, Igarashi and a Japanese script. Perhaps I'll be dead by the time that's a big issue. :)

@John yes, that's the suggestion. but if you're happy to stick with Latin script, just use T1 for output and Unicode input. what encoding does your .tex file use? the default has been UTF8 for quite some time in most editors etc., but if you're modifying a file which is old enough, it might be using something else.

এটি একটি ছোট পৃথিবী

"What encoding does my .tex file use"? I suspect it's all just ASCII. Maybe at some point it was saved as UTF-8 by some editor I used, but it's certainly all ASCII-looking to me -- I mostly only produce non-ASCII text by typing math in LaTeX.  Anyhow, I'll use the  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} thing and see where that gets me. A preliminary test makes me optimistic. Thanks, everyone.

One last question: if I were giving comments like this on math stackexchange, I'd often gather them into an answer labeled "community wiki" as a way to give the questioner something to "accept" and so that later readers could see the end result (and instantly know there's an accepted answer) without following a chain of comments. Is that something that's just not done here?

you could do that, or (more commonly) you could ask someone who commented to post the comment as an answer, but it's not as if any of the people who commented here are short of points and need some more, so feel free to post a collected answer

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} is the advice from the ancient world with only 8bit fonts. We have plenty of good Unicode fonts more than ten years. The 8bit fonts have no perspective. T1 encoded fonts (and fonts in T1 format too:) belongs to the old iron.

Of course the fact that something is old doesn't mean that you shouldn't use it - if T1 is sufficient for your needs (such as Turkish names) then it can be a good solution.

This should really be a comment rather than an answer. But I have read previous comments, and it seems that there was a certain amount of evasion. So, if I may be forgiven:
If at all possible, use lualatex for compiling, not pdflatex. Do not state font encoding. Forget about OT1 and T1. Write everything in utf-8, and \usepackage{fontspec}. Use fonts with OpenType or TrueType versions. You may directly paste letters (such as e with acute) from a character map, or the \'e code equivalent.
There are still some TeX fonts that are not available in OpenType or TrueType formats. There are ways to deal with them (see fontspec manual).
